# Any tools to automate UI testing of iOS ipad App

Tags: ios, automation, software-testing, user-interface, ipad-app

My company is using an iOS app that keeps having issues whenever there is a new release. Currently, for every new release, I need to perform regression testing on the app itself to ensure (at least the basic function) of the App is working as expected.

Recently, this app is undergoing a lot of changes and release is coming out twice monthly. It is taking up a lot of my time and my job is affected :(

I am looking for some tools that can automate my testing (by simulating my action clicking on the app).... Is there such a tool available? Hoping for some recommendation from experts here if there is such product.

Thanks in advance for the kind assistance

Comment: Google is awash with results for a search for `automated ios app gui testing`